# How to enable WPML to translate my content widget?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wpml

I'm developing a WordPress plugin and would like to know how I may translate a text from the plugin's database table using WPML.

Here's a sample of the code I want WPML to translate into multiple languages:

```
 echo esc_html_e('Contact with','my-plugin') ." ". esc_attr($name);

 *$name it's called from my plugin table in WordPress Database*
```

How do I translate "Contact with" and $name with WPML's multiple language support?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [String translation](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/string-translation/) for the translation of each string. If you don't see a string at first you will need to [find the strings first](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/string-translation/finding-strings-that-dont-appear-on-the-string-translation-page/).

For more details take a look at https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/translating-widgets